Card swiper flutter, no response swipe when press button
I used Card Swiper package and everything is fine. But when I use floating button to swipe a card to specific direction, nothing happens when press it.
Flexible(
  child: CardSwiper(
    controller: CardSwiperController(),
    cardsCount: flip_cards.length,
    onSwipe: _onswip,
    onUndo: _onUndo,
    isLoop: false,
    numberOfCardsDisplayed: 3,
    cardBuilder: (
      context,
      index,
      horizontalThresholdPercentage,
      verticalThresholdPercentage,
    ) =>
        flip_cards[index],
  ),
),


FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    controller.swipe(CardSwiperDirection.right);
  },
  child: const Icon(
    Icons.thumb_up,
    color: Colors.green,
    size: 80.0,
  ),
),

I tried to put setState() when press and change button to elevated button

You created CardSwiperController instance inside the CardSwiper. It should be the controller used in FloatingActionButton.

You mean use cardswipercontroller() instead of controller , already do it before

No, use controller, dont create a new instance. i.e CardSwiper(                 controller: controller,

thx bro :) you saved me

You created CardSwiperController instance inside the CardSwiper. It should be the controller used in FloatingActionButton.
